How to find the longest increasing subsequence in a circular buffer?
I am trying to solve a sorting problem in which it would be useful to determine the longest increasing subsequence in a circular buffer.
As an example, let's take the following sequence:
5, 3, 4, 2, 1
In the textbook problem we would consider this object to be an array and so the LIS here would simply be 3, 4.
However, if we consider this object to be a circular buffer, meaning the first element and the last element (or front and back) are connected, then the LIS could be 1, 3, 4 or also 2, 3, 4.
To be more clear, the sequence 5, 3, 4, 2, 1 is just one permutation of 1, 5, 3, 4, 2 where the front element has been pushed to the back.
Now my question is, is there a clever way to find the LIS for this kind of circular object?
I had the idea to apply a LIS algorithm to every single array permutation for the buffer but that would scale quadratically which would be terrible for performance.
I have a feeling there is a very simple answer to this question and maybe it is my lack of familiarity with LIS algorithms that is hindering me from seeing a more efficient solution..

Why can't you keep wrapping around? In your example you can always sort everything - it just takes going around 4x.

What do you mean by keep wrapping around? Trying every combination, the one that starts with 1, the one that starts with 2 and so on? I can't because the actual sequences I am working with are much larger that that, it could work but it's going to take too much time to be acceptable. But now that I think about it maybe I'm wrong about this is not going to take quadratic time. I'm not sure actually.

I would not called it a "double ended queue", as it is not a queue at all, but rather a circular buffer.

I suggest to change the title to circular buffer so there's a chance for someone else to search for it.

I have edited the question, circular buffer is more fitting, I agree.

Assuming it's about a circular buffer (i_1,..,i_n), you can reduce the problem to finding the LIS in the array (i_1,..,i_n,i_1,..,i_n-1).
The time complexity for this would be O(n' log n') with n'=2n-1.
Edit:†
To avoid sequences that span more than the initial buffer:
While building up the candidates you just remember the starting index of the first element, and avoid adding elements which are farther away than n-1. This check can be added to the LIS algorithm without affecting its time complexity.
† Thank you @KonstantinMakarov for pointing out the flaw in the first draft.

That's the simplest way to do it. In the case of an non strictly increasing subsequence (where elements can be equal), one has to also consider the extreme case where all the values of the array are equal, and check that the result returned is not larger than the original array.

Does this actually work? Consider the list 4, 8, 5, 1, 9, 6, 2, 7, 3.  The answer should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. Your approach will give 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

@btilly Since the queue is circular you can wrap around to the first element, but you need to stop where you started. So the right answer to your input should be 1 2 3 4 5 not 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8. The flaw in my algorithm was pointed out by @KonstantinMakarov and I'm waiting for him to write up an answer. If he doesn't want to I'll try myself, tomorrow maybe.

@KonstantinMakarov I've updated my answer.

Given 1,3,2, you find the LIS of  1,3,2,1,3, which is 1,2,3. Now what do you do with that?

The algorithm wouldn't allow to add 3 to the sequence 1 2 because its index (the one of the second 3) is more than n-1 places away from the index of the starting element, 1. @nocomment

Your answer says "finding the LIS in the array (i_1,..,i_n,i_1,..,i_n-1)". So you're not actually doing that?

Yes, but with the restriction from the edit section, so it's a modified LIS algorithm that also memorizes the starting index of any candidate, without worsening the time complexity. @nocomment

I think you'd better say that in the first paragraph then. I.e., don't say to find the LIS if that's not really the case. Btw I also don't find your modified algorithm clear and I'm not convinced it works. Would be good to see at least pseudocode.

This sounds like the best way to solve this problem for sure but I find it hard to understand why it works, especially the part where you need to "cut" the resulting buffer.
